# how to insert a row before pasting an array

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have an array which I populate and paste in a sheet named "T1" using a macro. My current macro uses the `rowcount` function to determine the used rows and pastes the array from the next available row.

The problem I am having is that when I paste this array multiple times, the arrays need to be spaced by a row so that i can differentiate different submissions.  This is what I have so far, and I was hoping someone could help me with this:

```
Sub CopyData()

     Dim Truearray() As String
     Dim cell As Excel.Range
     Dim RowCount1 As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim ii As Integer
     Dim col As Range
     Dim col2 As Range
     i = 0
     ii = 2

     RowCount1 = DHRSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
     Set col = DHRSheet.Range("I1:I" & RowCount1)

     For Each cell In col

         If cell.Value = "True" Then

             Dim ValueCell As Range
             Set ValueCell = Cells(cell.Row, 3)
             ReDim Preserve Truearray(i)
             Truearray(i) = ValueCell.Value

             Dim siblingCell As Range
             Set siblingCell = Cells(cell.Row, 2)
             Dim Siblingarray() As String

             ReDim Preserve Siblingarray(i)
             Siblingarray(i) = DHRSheet.Name & "$" & siblingCell.Value

             i = i + 1

         End If

     Next

     Dim RowCount2 As Integer

     RowCount2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

     For ii = 2 To UBound(Truearray)
         DataSheet.Cells(RowCount2 + ii, 2).Value = Truearray(ii)
     Next

     For ii = 2 To UBound(Siblingarray)
         DataSheet.Cells(RowCount2 + ii, 1).Value = Siblingarray(ii)
     Next

     DataSheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit

     MsgBox ("Data entered has been successfully validated & logged")

 End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use USEDRANGE. Use this methond to find the lastrow and then simply add 1 to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: I don't really understand the question, because the code already seems to do what it's supposed to. When you perform the line: Count2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 , you create a blank line before starting to fill out the TrueArray and SiblingArray. If you would paste the array multiple times (eg in a loop), you can just redefine the usedRange after each array paste. Won't that solve your problem?

Comment: - Or you can redefine the last cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Offset two rows from the bottom cell, you will leave a blank row of separation.  You should also consider filling the whole array as base 1 and writing it to DataSheet in one shot.

```
Sub CopyData2()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim aTrues() As Variant
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Define the range to search
    With DHRSheet
        Set rRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 9), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    End With

    'resize array to hold all the 'trues'
    ReDim aTrues(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRng, "True"), 1 To 2)

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell.Value = "True" Then
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            'store the string from column 2
            aTrues(lCnt, 1) = DHRSheet.Name & "$" & rCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
            'store the value from column 3
            aTrues(lCnt, 2) = rCell.Offset(0, -6).Value
        End If
    Next rCell

    'offset 2 from the bottom row to leave a row of separation
    With DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
        'write the stored information at one time
        .Resize(UBound(aTrues, 1), UBound(aTrues, 2)).Value = aTrues
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: nice one, as usual - good thing to comment, that will help the OP